# Linq query join has error

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to filter cases where I only want cases that have case_manager EmployeeId's that are in criteria.EmployeeId which is IEnumerable.

This SQL statement is an example of the joins

```
SELECT c.Id, c.filenumber, c.title, cm.[Role], e.fname, e.lname
FROM [CASE] c
INNER JOIN CASE_MANAGER cm ON c.Id = cm.CaseId
INNER JOIN tblEmployees e ON cm.EmployeeId = e.Id
WHERE e.Id IN (154, 311)
```

My filter:

```
if (criteria.EmployeeIds != null)
cases = cases.Where(c => c.CASE_MANAGER.Any(cm => cm.tblEmployee.id == criteria.EmployeeIds));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'IEnumerable<int>'
```

on this part of the filter:

cm.tblEmployee.id == criteria.EmployeeIds

How do I get this join correct with linq?

Comment: Looks like `criteria.EmployeeIds` is `IEnumerable<int>`. Use `criteria.EmployeeIds.Contains(cm.tblEmployee.id)`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. This basically is the LINQ equivalent of the SQL `IN` clause.